# Laravel 5.5 Undefined variable: result

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here's the PHP:

```
    if($criteria == 'schools'){
        $result = $result->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
    }elseif($criteria == 'bachelorsdegree'){
        $result = $result->where('undergradcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
    }elseif($criteria == 'mastersdegree'){
        $result = $result->where('postgradcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
    }elseif($criteria == 'technicalvocational'){
        $result = $result->where('technicalandvocationalcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
    }elseif($criteria == 'certificateshortcourse'){
        $result = $result->where('shortcoursesandcertifications', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
    }
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
        $result = $result->where('undergradcourses', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%');
```

It started when I took out this line:

```
 $result = schools::where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%');
```

Problem is: I took out the input field in the main search form that had the searchLocation field so I didn't want "searchLocation" to be in the search parameters anymore when you did a search.  The fields that exist in the search form is searchItem and the dropdown menu for degree types under the criteria of schools.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This was the original code before I added the location field and degree types dropdown menu:

```
    if($criteria == 'schools'){

    $first=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion,school_type) AGAINST('$type')");


    $result=schools::where([

        ['ownership', $ownership],

        ['location',$location],

        ['school_type',$type],

        ])

    ->orwhere([

        ['ownership', $ownership],

        ['location',$location]

        ])

    ->orwhere('fees',$fees)

    ->union($first)

    ->get();

    if(count($result)>0){

    $count=count($result);

    return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count));   

    }

    else{

        return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'criteria'=>$criteria));

    }
```

This is what my current $result code (the last snippet) looks like:

```
    $result = $result->paginate();
    if(count($result)>0){

        $count=count($result);

        return view('schools', [
            'result' => $result,
            'searchItem' => $searchItem, 
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'count' => $count, 
            'searchLocation' => $searchLocation, 
            'search' => $search,
            'minPrice' => $minPrice,
            'maxPrice' => $maxPrice,
            'minRank' => $minRank,
            'maxRank' => $maxRank,
            'returnData' => $returnData
        ]);

    }

    else{

        return view('schools', [
            'msg' => 'No result found',
            'count' => '0',
            'searchItem' => $searchItem,
            'criteria' => $criteria, 
            'searchLocation' => $searchLocation,
            'search' => $search,
            'minRank' => $minRank,
            'maxRank' => $maxRank,
            'returnData' => $returnData
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using switch statement for this case and post the error message. What does the error say? And try getting the result using ->get(). I think you need to get the result first. What is $result exactly getting?

Comment: Tip: use switch statement that if ... elseif

Comment: put code from start!

Comment: @RajeshPaudel post updated